# No persistent classes found when integration test in Gradle

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, gradle

My project bases on Spring+JPA+Hibernate, and use Ant to manage build process before, now I am  intending to use Gradle. While when run 'gradle clean test', I got a exception as below:

> [2013-02-07 11:01:36,703][Test worker][WARN ][QuerySplitter] no persistent classes found for query class: from com.mpos.lottery.te.workingkey.domain.WorkingKey w where w.createDateStr=:createDateStr and w.gpeId=:gpeId
>
> [2013-02-07 11:01:36,718][Test worker][ERROR][TEPortServlet] org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [gpeId]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [gpeId]

I have ran that test case(doesn't need jetty) in both eclipse and Ant, it passed, So i suspect that some incorrect configuration in gradle cause this exception.

Below is my gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
// 'war' plugin will apply 'java' plugin automatically
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
// run web application, refer to http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/jetty_plugin.html
apply plugin: 'jetty'

compileJava.options.encoding = _sourcecode_encoding
compileTestJava.options.encoding = _sourcecode_encoding

// Properties added by the java plugin
sourceCompatibility="${_source_compatibility}"
targetCompatibility="${_target_compatibility}"
//Properties added by the 'war' plugin
webAppDirName="src/main/WWW"

configurations {
    provided {
        description = 'Non-exported comiple-time dependencies, it will be provided by container.'
    }
}

dependencies {
    provided files('lib/DEV/j2ee/servlet-api.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '**/*.jar', exclude: 'DEV/**/*.jar')
    //compile sourceSets.main.output
    testCompile fileTree(dir:"lib", include:"DEV/**/*.jar")
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        compileClasspath = compileClasspath + configurations.provided
        //compileClasspath.collect().each({println it})
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/main/resource'
        }
    }
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/test/resource'
        }
    }
}

test {
    scanForTestClasses  = false
    classpath = configurations.provided + configurations.compile + configurations.testCompile + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
    classpath.each({println it})
    // customize test process
    include 'com/mpos/lottery/te/gameimpl/smsraffle/**/*Test.class'
}
```

I am new learner of Gradle and groovy, pls help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Gradle uses separate output directories for classes and resources, which can cause problems with Hibernate/JPA. Try:

```
sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
sourceSets.test.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.test.output.classesDir
```

You might not need the latter.

Comment: Thank you so much, Peter. It solved my problem, but i dont' understand why this occured, as i have printed out the classpath in 'test' task, and the classpath did include all those directories(build\classes\main, build\resources\main, build\classes\test, build\resources\test).

Comment: In short, JPA requires classes and resources to reside in the same directory.